# XML Base64 Binary Cotainer - How to decode, using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, base64, binaryfiles

I need to decode a XML-Container which contains Base64-Binary-Data.
The following code is just a little peace of the whole document but I think that you can see the format/schema. I don't know how to handle and base64_decode won't be the solution(?)

```
 <container>
 <header>
 <Identifier>
 <publicationId>2261000</publicationId>
 </Identifier>
 <ns2:Timestamp ns2:Id="body"> 
 <ns2:Created>2014-06-06T16:00:03.177Z</ns2:Created></ns2:Timestamp>
 </header>
 <body>
 <binary type="base64BinaryDatex2" id="B1">H4sIAAAAAAAAAOzdy5IbR5Yu6vl5ClgNdg+OOeT3i7Za23AlVSQlGckuHquZR4RHIoxIgBYASi3O
 ymyfNzjz/RY1qlHpxU5EklIlkQSECAUifwLe1l1NMe9/ZkZ9Wu5rrW/+13/fLgd/C+WmWK/+8z/Y
 kP7HIKzSdVasbv7zP/7r9ZzY//hf3/5f32T8+fqmSP3yxToLy0H1RqvNf/5psd2++/qrr263m7ff
 rfJ1eeu31bv5apMuwq3/ijJCafW/f/rw6l//96b47U1++umn4U9iuC5vvuKUsq/+nxfPX929FSlW
 m61fpaF6q03x9Yd39Xyd3r3nUz/i4MewLdfLV9u7l/64S5bFh3cw/O9N9qfBbf01jP0m/OXj1/0n
 /qdB+O9tWNX/9L2/Df/5p0Pv4d4r/vbWv32h337zzv+8XPvs3hvcfRnbn98dfZ9LX8X9p6z6oovs
 P//0hHDKJBFGqPpd/vsVJ2Xw23X57Tfperfalj9/m4Vvvvr1z9+s7l7HL7/Lwmpb5EUov53OyIvp
 CzLerbKwqb7LiV9lg3kZqpcNXvvV2802LJdhNQjDwV+G33z1mffwzVef+/g3YRXKIr33NdSpfXvo
 <!-- .... -->
```

Comment: You will need an XML parser, be able to read the document and then get to the part you want to decode. You will need to figure out what you want to use to parse the XML first. Im not sure people are just gonna write your code out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use base64_decode you need to pull out base64 encoded string out of XML:

```
// Load XML from $xml variable
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

// Now pull out <binary> elements with XPath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$list = $xpath->query("//binary");

// Now go through each base64 string and decode
$decoded = array();
foreach ($list as $binary)
  {
    $decoded[] = base64_decode($binary->nodeValue);
  }
```

Array $decoded will contain all decoded binary strings from your document